# después de instalar node.js " comando no encontrado"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, terminal, macos

hola que tal espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con lo siguiente .
después de instalar node.js trato de ejecutar el comando node -v para saber si todo salió bien y me dice "comando no encontrado" y por ende no puedo ejecutar npm install

tengo un macOS high sierra version 10.13.1

Comment: te invito a leer esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/10630762/5695795

Comment: instale node por medio de su instalador  .pkg  y también intente mediante brew

Comment: Si previa a la instalación en windows has tenida la terminal abierta, y luego has utilizado la misma para consultar la versión de node `node -v`, te recomiendo que cierres la terminal y la vuelvas a iniciar como administrado. Si has realizado la instalación en linux, definitivamente algo no has echo bien!

Comment: La última línea de la pregunta dice: `'tengo un macOS high sierra version 10.13.1'`. Dudo mucho que le sirva una respuesta para windows o linux :-)